# SQL inner join UPDATE Query Across tables?

Tags: mysql

Two tables, as below.

```
tbl-1
------
userid
teamid
teamname
elimimated


tbl-2
------
teamid
selectedteam
```

I want to update tbl-1.eliminated =  1 IF tbl-2.selectedteam is null? How can I achieve this in one sql command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl-1 SET eliminated=1 
WHERE teamid IN (
                    SELECT t2.teamid FROM tbl-2 AS t2
                    RIGHT JOIN tbl-1 AS t1
                    ON t2.teamid = t1.teamid
                    WHERE t2.selectedteam IS NULL
               );
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error (note I need to join tbl-1 in the 2nd select statement) "1093 - You can't specify target table 'tbl-1' for update in FROM clause"